# Sending data between ViewController with JASidePanels

Tags: ios

I am trying to implement JASidePanels where CenterViewController slides and reveals LeftViewControler which contains a TableView. Once the user selects a row in the TableView, I'd like the CenterView to regain it's position by sliding back and also have a method (within CenterViewController) do be called with a parameter from LEftViewController to update the CenterView. Can somebody please help my with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Jasidepanel is a nice control but there are other controls which are easier to implement for you. Try the one in my answer it is less confusing for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to solving your problem:

1. first showing center panel when user select a row:

[self.viewController showCenterPanelAnimated:YES];
// add this method to your tableView row

1. passing a message back to center panel with new instruction, this can be done by creating delegate or notification. to keep it simple i will use Notification:

in your left panel class:

```
 // Add to your tableView row method
    NSNotification *msg = [NSNotification notificationWithName:@"leftPanelMsg" object:@"Hello"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:msg];
```

in your center panel class:
add Observer in viewDidLoad and another method when message is passed back:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // method listen to meesssage with specfic name and calls selector when it get hit
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(msgResponder:) name:@"leftPanelMsg" object:nil];
    }

-(void)msgResponder:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"name:%@ object:%@", notification.name, notification.object);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Definitely the easiest way to do it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Works well, but why it's called twice? NSLog is printed twice

Comment: @CGR i never experiance this issue on iOS 7-9. i could only assume there a bug in the code base

Comment: I noticed that `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` is called twice, one when the storyboard is going to be displayed and the second one when I reveal the right panel, code resides in `viewDidLoad` I'm using the same class for both, this also happen to you? :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use delegates, then you have to add a protocol to the LeftViewController.h file, e.g.

```
@protocol LeftViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)useThisValue:(NSString *)value;

@end

@interface LeftViewController : UITableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <LeftViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, you can then add

```
[self.delegate useThisValue:menu[indexPath.row]];
```

Your CenterViewController will become the delegate of the LeftViewController, so in your CenterViewController.h file, import the LeftViewController.h and add:

```
@interface CenterViewController : UIViewController <LeftViewControllerDelegate>

- (void)useThisValue:(NSString *)value;
```

In your CenterViewController.m file, import both the AppDelegate.h and your RootViewController.h file. In its viewDidLoad method, you have to get a reference to the current instances of your JASidePanelController subclass (RootViewController) and the leftViewController:

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = (RootViewController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

LeftViewController *leftViewController = (LeftViewController *)rootViewController.leftPanel;
```

and then make the CenterViewController the delegate of the LeftViewController:

```
leftViewController.delegate = self;

[super viewDidLoad];
```

Implement the delegate method however you wish, for example:

```
- (void) useThisValue:(NSString *)value
{
     self.label.text = value;
}
```

I have to acknowledge and thank Kevin McNeish here for pointing out to me how to properly get the instances of the RootViewController and the LeftViewController in order to get the delegate pattern to work with JASidePanels.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm wondering if it's possible to include  "UIViewController+JASidePanel.h" and use that instead of finding the root controller and left panel?  I'm trying it and the left panel keeps coming up as nil.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see these methods in JASidePanels

```
// toggle them opened/closed
- (void)toggleLeftPanel:(id)sender;
- (void)toggleRightPanel:(id)sender;
```

JASidePanels is a good implementation, you can set the left, center and the right view controllers. So lets say that you have a UITableViewController as the left VC and according to row selection you load the center VC. You should have #import "UIViewController+JASidePanel.h" in your left VC.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  switch (indexPath.row)

case 1:
{
    self.sidePanelController.centerPanel = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[FirstViewController alloc] init]];
[self.sidePanelController toggleLeftPanel:nil];
break;
}

case 2:
{
self.sidePanelController.centerPanel = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[SecondViewController alloc] init]];
[self.sidePanelController toggleLeftPanel:nil];
break;
}

}
```

Comment: toggleLeftPanel hides the table, it make the nex view smooth but a notice able blink on the screen as Table hides. but when you slide the center panel, table is already there, then why it is hiding the table.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily hides a table View , it hides the leftPanelController that is set in JASidePanel initialization. The view controller is sitting there already, the center panel just moves away from its original co-ords.